# How to increase vcores per container in tez task?

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I am trying to configure vcores per container for tez task. I have edited the property tez.task.resource.cpu.vcores but tez is not taking the value, it always allocates one vcore per requested container.

How to increase vcores per container in tez?

Comment: you also need to make sure that yarn is configured to manage vcores. default yarn settings only use memory based allocation

Comment: @Raid what properties in yarn need to be configured for assigning vcores per container ?

Comment: Refer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManagerCgroups.html